# Python: Another way to sort without using built-in sort function?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

We represent a person using a `tuple(<gender>, <age>)`. Given a list of people, write a function sort_age that sorts the people and return a list in an order such that the older people are at the front of the list. An example of the list of people is `[("M", 23), ("F", 19), ("M", 30)]`. The sorted list would look like `[("M", 30), ("M", 23), ("F", 19)]`.

My approach:

```
def sort_age(lst):
   lst.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]),reverse=True)
   return lst
```

Is there another way to do this without using .sort?

Comment: Yes, if you implement a sorting algorithm yourself.

Comment: if you think `lambda` is complex, then try implementing a performant sort algorithm, in native python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def custom_sort(lst):
    for i in range(0,len(lst)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(lst)):
            if lst[i][1]<lst[j][1]:
                lst[i],lst[j]=lst[j],lst[i]
    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a copy of input, without modifying the input itself, that would be `sorted`, e.g.:

```
l2 = list(sorted(l1, key=lambda x: -x[1]))
```